# when to use display.getdefault().asyncexe() & display.getdefault().syncexec()?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to display `ProgressBar` on my `Shell`. So here is [the scenario](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byl-cbqAFVt1akZQTHlVVEtIc1E) When I click on "Next" button from wizard page below method is called :

(1) `checkProblems()`: which checks problem and if problem found then show `MessageBox` saying that "Your system has problem, Do you want to fix it?" If User click on OK button, another `Shell` having `ProgressBar` and Status will be opened, and gradually I will set progress and update status.

Once Fixing utility is finished, I call another method to read file whether it has error or not. If there is no error, I show `MessageBox` saying "Your Problem has been resolved, Press OK to continue".

I created `Thread t = new Thread()` in starting of `checkProblems()` method and try to wrap methods in `Display.getDefault.asyncexec()` & `syncexec()` but when `ProgressBar` shell get opens, it hangs up for a while and the progress doesn't set and directly I get the message that "Your problem is resolved". The entire execution goes well but I want to display a `ProgressBar` with some status about what is going on behind the scene.

Please help me where should I write `Display.getDefault.asyncexec()` & `syncexec()`

Comment: On a `WizardPage` you should be using `setMessage` to set error messages at the top of the wizard and using the wizard container `run` method to run a `IRunnableWithProgress` to do work needing progress which will uses the wizard's built in progress bar.

Comment: In a wizard page class, i have nextPressed() method from where checkProblems() invokes. Entire business logic is in another class which extends Dialog where i have written this method checkProblems() in which i have business logic to check problems and open MessageBox. I have created method say setProgress(int progressVal,String statusMsg){Display.getDefault().asyncexec() where in i am setting objProgressBar.setProgress(progressValue) and shellLabelMsg.setText(statusMsg). I invoke this setProgress() starting of each methods. Should i wrap this methods with asyncexec() or syncexec() ?